# inspecting the .hex file generated by gpasm

Tags: disassembly, objdump

To answer my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71024004/4999991), I wrote a small sample program, `example.asm`:

```
var_1 equ H'0001'

    constant var_2=H'0002'

#define var_3 H'0003'

cblock H'0004'
    var_4
endc

    END
```

and compiled it with gpasm using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68140917/4999991), `Makefile`

```
all: example.asm    
    gpasm -p p10f200 example.asm 

clean:
    rm -f *.hex *.lst *.cod *.asm~
```

Now inspecting the `example.hex` file with `hexdump -C example.hex`, I get:

```
00000000  3a 30 32 30 30 30 30 30  34 30 30 30 30 46 41 0a  |:020000040000FA.|
00000010  3a 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  31 46 46 0a              |:00000001FF.|
0000001c
```

which I have no clue how to interpret, and the `objdump -d example.hex`, throws this error:

```
example.hex:     file format ihex

objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!
```

eventually I want to know what are the differences between the above four different methods of defining a constant and compare their performance and memory efficiency.

Comment: Isn't `.hex` already a text file?  Looks like you're hex-dumping an ASCII hex dump, not a `.bin`

Comment: Dear @PeterCordes , My apologies. I am absolutely ignorant about the topic. My final goal is to compare the compiled version of the above four syntax and see the differences.  Where did I go wrong, and how should I do that instead?

Comment: They're text files, so `diff -u foo1.hex foo2.hex`.  And/or just look at them with a text editor you know how to use, or a GUI diff tool like `meld`.  Of course, you don't use any of the constants, so like we explained in comments on [your SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024004/what-are-the-differences-between-different-ways-to-define-a-constant-from-perfor), no part of the assemblers output corresponds to them at all; your output is the same as for an empty file.  And if you did use them, they'd all be equivalent (or would be if you'd used the same numbers)

Comment: you are defining not using there will be no assembly generated for defines and no efficiency calculations can be done you need to burn cycles for calculating efficiency performance , etc

Comment: btw as cordes commented the hex files are ascii files use notepad to open them not hexeditor

Comment: there seems to be a gpdasm available as per the doc link you posted which is capable of taking the hex file and disassemble it why not try using it instead of hexdump or objdump ?